# Adding additional dependencies for all files with a given extension

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's say I am using the implicit rule to build an `.o` file from a `.c` file.

If I want to add a specific additional dependency for one particular `.o` file, it is as easy as adding a rule without a recipe:

```
file.o : header.h
```

This makes `file.o` depend on `header.h` in addition to `file.c`.

What if I want to do that for *all* `.o` files? The following doesn't work:

```
%.o : header.h
```

Comment: The short answer is no, you cannot take your entire existing makefile as-is and add one extra line like the above to force all objects to depend on that header.  You will have to either change all existing targets that build `.o` files, or else write a rule like `_allobjs_ : header.h` where _allobjs_ is a list of all the object files.  For example if you have all your source file  in a variable `SRCS` you could write: `$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS)) : header.h`

Answer (score 2):

For this to make sense, `header.h` must a header that is (and has to be) included by every `.c` file
and is hence a prerequisite of every `.o` file. If that is your situation you
need to write your own pattern rule, like:

```
%.o: %.c header.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

But the usual approach to managing header file dependencies is [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)

**Later**

> My goal was to avoid duplicating the existing implicit rule (the recipe part) for $(CC) compilation. Is that possible?

You have to define a new pattern rule that *adds* `header.h` to the `%.c` prerequisite,
and has the appropriate recipe. In fact I ought
to have advised you also to [*cancel*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) the builtin pattern rule:

```
%.o: %.c

%.o: %.c header.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: My goal was to avoid duplicating the existing implicit rule (the recipe part) for $(CC) compilation. Is that possible?

Comment: @BeeOnRope We don't want any duplication, we want *replacement*. Extended answer.

Comment: Right, I mean it's duplication in the sense that I have to write out explicitly the exact same recipe that the implicit rule already uses, just to satisfy my orthogonal requirement of adding more dependencies?

Comment: About "For this to make sense", I don't agree. It may be a conservative approximation: some `.o` files may not depend on the header, but if I'm willing to say they all do, everything will be correct and I'll simply suffer some not-strictly-necessary additional compilations (but of course any build system has plenty of not strictly necessary recompilations).

Comment: Hi. Tolerance of a few unnecessary compilations isn't unreasonable, but if I
discovered any in the autotooled make-system of some important package I'd report a bug.
Auto-dependency generation - which has built in support in GCC and comes out-of-the-box with [Automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/)
*is* the routine way of having a GNU Make build system compute all
its own header file dependency rules.

Comment: yes I use auto-dependency generation in any project with more than a few header files. I'm talking about a makefile here with less than 10 lines and a handful of files. Furthermore, the question stands for any relationship besides `.c` and `.h`, where auto-dependency doesn't necessarily exist (including even C with compilers like MSVC that don't support it in the same way or at all).